# Markings/marks/pencil marks

Tags: grammar

1. Markings on your skin.
2. Marks on your skin.
3. Pencil marks on your skin.
4. A pencil mark on your skin.

How is each different from each other and what context would be proper for each?

Comment: Which dictionary definitions for *mark* and *markings* have you found so far? I think you should include that in your question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Marking* means something done with a pen, paint, or other instrument (e.g. tattoos, skin paintings, etc.).  *Marking* is clearest when talking about these.

*Mark*, on skin, could be any area or line that is not the usual skin color.  Moles, pimples, scratches, birthmarks are all types of marks on skin.  If one uses the term *marking* in reference to these, the implication is that it is not naturally caused or someone has done it to mark you for a reason (think witchcraft).

*Mark* however can be used to mean the same as *marking*, but generally not the other way around.